# The fastest way to read csv data to Time class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, performance, csv

I've been trying to parse time-series Forex csv data(more than 100MB) to Ruby program.
But I'm facing dificulty to deal with speed problem.

The csv Data are like below.
It contains "Date", "Time", "Open", "Close", "High", "Low", "Volume" in order.

```
2007.01.02,07:00,119.01,119.01,119.01,119.01,8
2007.01.02,07:01,119.01,119.01,119.01,119.01,8
2007.01.02,07:02,119.01,119.01,119.01,119.01,8
2007.01.02,07:03,119.01,119.02,119.01,119.02,8
2007.01.02,07:04,119.02,119.03,119.01,119.02,8
```

I wrote a script to import it.
I avoided using CSV library because it was too slow to parse CSV file.
(Like CSV.parse CSV.foreach)

```
IO.foreach(csv) do |line|
  res = line.split(",")
  Time.parse("%s %s"%[res[0], res[1]])
  res[2].to_f
  res[3].to_f
  res[4].to_f
  res[5].to_f
  res[6].to_i
end
```

When I executed this program, Time.parse was too slow.
The csv file has 2.5 million lines, so it undergoes 2.5 million times.

The comparative results are below.

- With Time.parse : 160 seconds.
- With Time.local : 56 seconds. (modified csv data)
- With Time.at : 23 seconds.    (modified csv data)
- Without Time Parse : only 10 seconds.

When I commented out Time.parse, it became much faster.
I know Time.now and Time.new with no argument is fast.

Could anybody have a good idea?
I don't hesitate to make C library for Ruby if it make the program much faster.

Thank you.

Environment

- Windows 7 x64
- ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]

---

I uploaded my project to Github.
https://github.com/pgkireek/ruby_trade

Comment: Could you consider using a database instead of csv. Or you have to parse csv generated somewhere... Since it's related to trading.

Comment: I've already made most program with in-memory sqlite3, but it's not enough fast. So I'm trying to read file directly to confirm whether it could make it faster.

Comment: Try using Time.new(2007,5,5,7,00)  but you will have to convert res[0] and res[1] into integers first, or if the csv can pass those in integer from the start

Comment: Thank you. Time.new takes 57 seconds. Time.at takes 23 seconds. Currently Time.at is fastest. I updated the article because the result informations were wrong. Sorry for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you could use with regex instead. Match all the group and use them in `Time.new`.

```
IO.foreach(csv) do |line|
    res = line.scan /((\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)|(\d+):(\d+)|(\d+)\.(\d+)|\d+)/
    puts Time.new res[0][1], res[0][2], res[0][3], res[1][4], res[1][5]

    puts res[2][0].to_f
    puts res[3][0].to_f
    puts res[4][0].to_f
    puts res[5][0].to_f
    puts res[6][0].to_i
end
```

Not sure but it could be much faster using the regex instead of split.

Comment: Thank you. It's better than Time.parse.

Comment: Can you tell me what OP meant to say, by doing `to_f` and `to_i`, where as those entries are already float and fixnum, at that positions?

Comment: @ArupRakshit they are strings, you have to convert them to int/float when required.